# how to find recent committers of a file in git?

Tags: git, blame

Is there a way to find who recently changed a file in git?

For exaxmple, I need last 5 people who changed this file. I tried `git annotate` and `git blame` but I could not find the exact thing I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

git shortlog does what you want:

```
git shortlog -sne <filename>
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the most efficient or sensible way, but this seems to work:

```
$ git log <filepath> | grep Author: | cut -d' ' -f2- | uniq | head -n5
```

This is assuming you actually want the last 5 *authors*, irrespective of how many commits each of them might have made. If you just want the last 5 commits then `git log` alone can be used:

```
$ git log -5 <filepath>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
git log filename
```

You can play around with the log output (see man git-log)  to get just the info you want.

Comment: There is already an answer, made before you, that already mentions `git log` and provides the complete one-liner to get the author. Please delete your answer in order to deduplicate information. (I know you likely didn't see it at the time because it was made almost at the same time, and I'm not questioning the absolute value of your answer, just saying that there's a strictly superior answer already there, and that this would help visibility of information in the thread for people coming here in the future :) )

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful to display the last 5 authors of a single file

```
git log -n 5 --pretty='format:%an' -- path/to/file
```

*`-n <number>`* - number of commits (in this case authors) to be displayed

*`--pretty='format:%an'`* - display only the author name

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
 gitk filename
```

Thorsten

Comment: what is gitk? care to elaborate?